# Can I put custom text/characters/glyphs as the icon for a choice snippet suggestion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am creating my own snippet to insert characters from Greek alphabet. How can I add a symbol to each row in dropdown?

I want the "α" symbol in place of that yellow icon - is it possible?

[image: dropdown]

here is my snippet:

```
  "Greek Alphabet": {
    "prefix": "galphabet",
    "body": ["${1|\\alpha,\\Alpha,\\beta,\\Beta,\\gamma,\\Gamma,\\delta,\\Delta,\\epsilon,\\Epsilon,\\zeta,\\Zeta,\\eta,\\Eta,\\theta,\\Theta,\\kappa,\\Kappa,\\lambda,\\Lambda,\\mu,\\Mu,\\nu,\\Nu,\\xi,\\Xi,\\omicron,\\Omicron,\\pi,\\Pi,\\rho,\\Rho,\\sigma,\\Sigma,\\tau,\\Tau,\\upsilon,\\Upsilon,\\phi,\\Phi,\\chi,\\Chi,\\psi,\\Psi,\\omega,\\Omega|} $0"]
    "description": "Greek Alphabet",
  },
```

Comment: that icon is a rep that this is a literal text, snippets are squares

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know, it is not possible to put snippet choice description texts in place of the suggestion type icon- short of making a custom build of VS Code where you make it so.

I don't see any existing feature requests to enable specifying description texts for each choice in the choice snippet in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Asnippets+label%3Afeature-request either. So you could [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) like "Allow giving each choice in a snippet its own description text".

Comment: I see. So is there any other way I could add that symbol on the line?

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.